# Pretty print __str__ of custom python objects

Tags: python, python-3.x

In the following two classes:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import List

@dataclasses
class A:
    statements: List[str]
    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return "\n".join(f"{s}" for s in self.statements)
@dataclasses
class B:
    objects: List[A]
    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return "From B\n".join(f"{o}" for o in self.objects)
```

is there a way to print them in a pretty way respecting also indentation. Meaning that when I only print object A I will get a list of whatever it holds:

**A**

```
hello
world
```

and when I print B I will have:

**B**

```
From B
    hello
    world
```

My own tests only ident the first object:

```
>>> a = A(statements=[1, 2, 3])
>>> b = A(statements=[4, 5, 6])
>>> print(a)
1
2
3
>>> dd = B(objects=[a, b])
>>> print(dd)
From B
    1
2
3
    4
5
6
```

Comment: What is wrong with the code you have?

Comment: @ScottHunter it does not do what I need it to do. Let me add a more complete example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [textwrap](https://docs.python.org/3/library/textwrap.html#textwrap.indent) module from the standard library:

```py
>>> from dataclasses import dataclass
>>> from typing import List
>>> import textwrap

>>> @dataclass
    class A:
        statements: List[str]
        def __str__(self) -> str:
            return "\n".join(f"{s}" for s in self.statements)

    @dataclass
    class B:
        objects: List[A]
        def __str__(self) -> str:
            return "From B\n" + textwrap.indent(
                "\n".join(str(o) for o in self.objects),
                "    ",
            )

>>> alphas = [A(statements=[1, 2, 3]), A(statements=[4, 5, 6])]
>>> beta = B(objects=alphas)
>>> delta = B(objects=[beta])
>>> print(str(delta))
From B
    From B
        1
        2
        3
        4
        5
        6
```

Comment: This doesn't work, because it only indents the first line.

Comment: @ekhumoro @dearn44 I don't think you're right. Are you using `print` to display the results? I'll update with an example.

Comment: @damon I think the issue is when `o`'s string representation itself has multiple lines.

Comment: @damon your example is pretty straightforward but my issue is when I have complex objects each one with its own `__str__` method that potentially prints lists. See my edited answer, it should be more clear now.

Comment: @dearn44 I've updated my answer to use `textwrap`. It should work with multiple levels of nesting as in my example.